# How to quickly fill cannelloni tubes with relatively dry mixture

Tags: equipment, pasta, italian-cuisine

We got some cannelloni delivered by mistake so I'm going to be making this for the first time. Having cooked many other pasta varieties, the sauces look fairly straightforward. However, this particular recipe suggests filling the tubes with cooked mince so it is going to be quite dry.

If the mince was wet, I'd probably allow it to cool and use a piping bag, but what is the easiest way if it is dry? The recipe suggests filling with a teaspoon but I'm making quite a large batch so this could take some time!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A piping bag might still work if the filling is moist such that it has at least a bit of lubrication, and as long as the mince is thoroughly broken up during cooking. If it binds even with the largest nozzle, you could also consider a plastic freezer bag with a corner removed. In either case the idea is not to use it to pack the filling in, just to quickly deliver some without spilling it all over. In either case, fill the tubes loosely, pack as desired with a spoon, and fill some more.